# How do you write "wild blueberries flavored"?

Tags: hyphens, attributive-nouns

How do you write "wild blueberries flavored"?

I am wondering if we need to add hyphens (-) and how many. So, for example, is it "wild-blueberries flavored" or "wild-blueberries-flavored" or something else. I am not sure what's the proper way to write this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the singular (*blueberry*) in general when you describe a flavor. I think the hyphens are optional and that any of the following would look ok:

> wild-blueberry-flavored
>
> wild blueberry-flavored
>
> wild blueberry flavored

The fourth option, *wild-blueberry flavored*, doesn't look right to me, because if you want to connect the words, *flavored* should be one of the words you connect - *flavored* is the main adjective that you are describing with other adjectives.

In general hyphens are most useful when they make the meaning of a phrase less ambiguous. There are some good examples of when hyphens are necessary [here](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-a-hyphen?page=1) - e.g. *small-state senator* vs. *small state senator*; *violent-weather conference* vs. *violent weather conference*. In your case the meaning of the phrase doesn't really change based on how you hyphenate it.

Comment: Ok, but *wild flavored* doesn't make sense so I don't think that any hyphens are required. So it seems obvious that wild qualifies blueberry and then "wild blueberry" qualifies flavor. // Although I don't know German, my impression is that often German handles this sort of idea better by making a compound word for the whole phrase.

Comment: @MaxW I agree, "wild flavored" makes no sense. But maybe "wild" could describe the noun N that follows, so "wild blueberry-flavored N" might not be the best option, despite what I wrote. I think most people would understand the implicit parentheses around "wild blueberry" in "wild blueberry-flavored" though - since "wild blueberry" is a relatively well-known fruit.

Comment: If I were going to put one hyphen in the phrase I'd use "wild-blueberry flavored."

Comment: @MaxW I guess that could work if you want to be clear that "wild blueberry" is a phrase. Probably best to use two hyphens or no hyphens to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Nouns like "blueberry" are usually singular when used in a compound as an adjective.  For example:

> Peach-colored
>
> Rose-hued
>
> Blueberry-flavored

And so on.  "Wild blueberry" is just a specific variety of this compound.  Hyphens are optional, but they do help connect the words to each other so that it's easier to understand what you mean

> I'd like to try some of that new **wild-blueberry-flavored** yogurt.

Of course, in many cases the difference between "wild blueberry" and "cultivated blueberry" flavors exists only in some marketing guy's head, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: Wild blueberries are around a third the size of cultivated blueberries and have a distinctive flavor. (Although whether there's any real difference between, say, wild-blueberry-flavored soda and blueberry-flavored soda is a different question.)